# Keep perl script running after ssh disconnect

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu

Is there a native way to keep a perl script running on a server(uninterrupted by ssh disconnections) without the use of tools like tmux and screen ? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the POSIX command [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Most shells also come with [`disown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_%28Unix%29)

As far as a perl native solution, you can simply use the [signal handling](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) features of perl.

```
$SIG{HUP} = sub {
  print "got SIGHUP\n";
};
```

Comment: lets say i want to go with nohub. Assuming i want to see the state of the script i was running in the background is it possible ? like pull the daemon from background to foreground :-D hope thats not stupid ahaha

Comment: If you want to reattach the process then you need `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: @user3066913 If you just want to see the current *output* of your script with `nohup`, write it to a file: `nohup ./myscript > myscript.log 2>&1`

Comment: @TheSuitIsBlackNot, `nohup` automatically redirects (appends) output to `nohup.out` or `$HOME/nohup.out` if possible, but your command is good if you want to put it in a specific place.  However, it redirects `stderr` to `stout` automatically, so that part is not needed at all.

Comment: Using the default output file doesn't work so well if you want to do this for multiple processes at once, but you're right, for most cases it's fine. I didn't realize that `nohup` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` for you...I've wasted so many keystrokes over the years :(

Answer (score 1):

[`screen`](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) is what you are looking for.

Comment: He did specify not screen or tmux.  But I do agree that it's still the best solution.